# Where is the location of last torch in this location?

Tags: unepic

[image]
[image]

I cannot found any torchlight left in this area yet the room is still marked as incomplete. Can someone tell me where is the location of the missing torchlight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is still a door you have yet not opened in that room. Take a look to the right wall of the lower room. You will need the library key to reach it, however.

[image: screenshot with the area highligthed]

You will find the rest of the torches there.

Comment: Okay so I need the library key first before accessing the gate right?

Comment: @NoTalentGeek Yes